# Compile Error: UniData LSELECT

Tags: select, compiler-errors, basic, unidata

I've found the [LSELECT](https://u2devzone.rocketsoftware.com/accelerate/articles/u2-select/u2-select/#section-8) program on the rocket software website but I'm having issues compiling it.

Has anyone had success with it?

Here are the errors:

```
:BASIC BS LSELECT

Compiling Unibasic: BS/LSELECT in mode 'm'.
main program: syntax error at or before
<line 126> GETLIST SOURCE.LIST TO 9 ELSE
           -----------------------^
Expecting: array,variable

Warning: there are some statements after END near line 132
error: the following labels are used but have not been defined:
SHOW.MESSAGE
FINISH.UP
BUILD.LIST2
LOAD.TEMP.FILE
CREATE.TEMP.FILE
  near line 243
compilation failed
```

Answer (score 2):

There are different flavors for TCL commands and also Basic programs.  It allows you to port code from different legacy systems to Unidata and not have to do a complete rewrite.  This code is written for the Unidata basic flavor.  You can switch to that temporarily in your session by doing:

```
:BASICTYPE "U"
```

Or add a compiler directive to the top of the program that tells Unidata which Basic sub-syntax to use.  They're all very close, with pretty minor differences.

```
$BASICTYPE "U"
```

https://docs.rocketsoftware.com/nxt/gateway.dll/RKBnew20/unidata/previous%20versions/v7.2/unidata_unibasicapplicationsdevguide_v72.pdf

Pick-style is a common default because much of the code running on Unidata is ported from older Pick or Pick-compatible systems.  So a lot of applications set BASICTYPE "P" and ECLTYPE "P" in the LOGIN paragraph for compatibility. According to "HELP BASICTYPE" the M option is for McDonnell Douglas or Reality flavors.

ECLTYPE is the other common thing to want to tweak - it controls how certain command arguments are processed.  The most useful is TO DELIM or TO XML which are only available in ECLTYPE U.  The trick there is that lower case command names are always evaluated in ECLTYPE U, so you don't have to always be switching back and forth - just use lower case if you want those "modern" extensions from the 90's ;-)

Comment: Have you tried to implement the LSELECT from Rocket's website? I tried switching the BASICTYPE to U, which worked, but ended up with other compiling errors.

Comment: `:BASIC BS LSELECT

Compiling Unibasic: BS/LSELECT in mode 'm'.

Basictype is changed, BS/LSELECT is compiling in mode 'u'

undefined compilation directive $OPTIONS near line 194

main program: syntax error at or before
<line 194> $OPTIONS -VAR.SELECT
           ---------^
Expecting: end-of-line,array,label,variable,verb,END,MAT,COM,ON,BREAK,PAGE,GOSUB
`

Comment: I did BASICTYPE "U" from TCL and the program compiled fine.

Comment: Philip, can you try typing BASICTYPE "U" from the TCL prompt - the program compiles for me if I do that.